# F#: Can units of measure be bound dynamically at runtime?

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I'm very new to F# and am intrigued by the Units of Measure functionality and have a rough idea of how it works normally, but would like to know if it's possible to bind measures to values where we don't know what the measure will be until the code is executing?

The practical example I'm looking at is binding floats as currency values where the unit of measure is inferred from a database lookup.

Let's assume that the measures for each currency (USD, EUR, AUD, etc) are declared normally:

```
[<Measure>] USD
[<Measure>] EUR
[<Measure>] AUD
...
```

First you would need a way to obtain a measure's type from an identifier, ideally the measure name itself as the currency code is most likely stored and retrieved as a 3-character string (similar to `Enum.Parse()`).

Then you would need a way of binding a float value to the type created in the previous step.

Is this possible, or is there another way to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: That is exactly the first limitation I saw with units of measure and made me not use them in the first place. actually the case should be some generic measures, like currency<'u>, or measure inheritance, because all the interesting action should take place at compile time.

Comment: did you end up using UoM at all ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible, since F# units-of-measure are erased (they only exist at compile-time).

You could author a library with a runtime implementation (I haven't thought about what a design would look like).  But you probably lose the static checking.

I think possibly a better strategy may be to isolate the boundary, and at the boundary point (where you read from the database and infer the unit types) somehow get the right types into the type system, but depending on how the code is structured and what exactly you're doing, that may or may not be possible/easy...

Comment: That makes sense - I'm guessing that's because there's no IL support for units of measure. I've already got a solution in C# and can port to F#, just wondered if there might be a more 'novel' approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are writing code that is actually specific to one particular currency, you shouldn't explicitly mention USD, EUR, AUD etc in your code. Instead, make your code polymorphic over the currency/currencies involved.

What you have to think about is what kinds of safety you are expecting to get from units of measure. If for example (in a very simplistic scenario) you would be reading from a database field, doing some processing and writing back to that same field, then having a function of type `float<'a> -> float<'a>` is exactly what you want: you don't care what the currency is, so long as you get back the same one you put in.