# Comparing F# discriminated union instances via pattern matching

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

Firstly, apologies for the poor title - I don't understand enough F# to describe the problem better.

Consider this simple DU:

```ml
type Money =
    | USD of decimal
    | GBP of decimal
    | EUR of decimal
    static member (+) (first: Money, second: Money) =
        match first, second with 
        | USD(x), USD(y) -> USD(x + y)
        | GBP(x), GBP(y) -> GBP(x + y)
        | EUR(x), EUR(y) -> EUR(x + y)
        | _ -> failwith "Different currencies"
```

I'm representing money in different currencies, and overloading the (+) operator so that I can safely do Money + Money. However, if I have many currencies then the match statement will become tedious to write. Is there any way of expressing something like:

```ml
match first, second with 
| _(x), _(y) -> _(x + y)
```

Or is there a different way to achieve the same result? I've considered and discarded units of measure due to the limitations described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140247/f-can-units-of-measure-be-bound-dynamically-at-runtime).

Comment: Shouldn't you be using units of measure for this in F#?

Comment: I'd love to use units of measure, but because the measure is erased at runtime it doesn't offer me any safety when reading data from external sources (see linked question). I'd love to be proved wrong!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
type Kind = | USD | GBP | EUR

type Money = 
    | Money of Kind * decimal 
    static member (+) (first: Money, second: Money) = 
        match first, second with  
        | Money(k1,x), Money(k2,y) when k1=k2 -> Money(k1, x + y) 
        | _ -> failwith "Different currencies"
```

Comment: Damn! Single-case DUs, I think they really deserve more attention:)