# F# comparing discriminated unions' by case identifier

Tags: .net, reflection, f#, discriminated-union

Is there a way to compare discriminated unions by their case-identifiers in F#?

```
type MyUnion =
| MyString of string
| MyInt of int

let x = MyString("hello")
let y = MyString("bye")
let z = MyInt(25)

let compareCases a b =
// compareCases x y = true
// compareCases x z = false
// compareCases y z = false
```

**How do I implement `compareCases` function in a generic way?**

I.e. something like the following, but more generic (reflection is ok):

```
let compareCases a b =
  match a with
  | MyString(_) -> match b with | MyString(_) -> true | _ -> false
  | MyInt(_) -> match b with | MyInt(_) -> true | _ -> false
```

Comment: This is very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686911/comparing-f-discriminated-union-instances-via-pattern-matching

Comment: Thanks, it looks interesting, but it has all the cases backed up by the same type and I'm not sure how it can be applied to my situation with different types.

Comment: If `Tag` were a supported exposed property, it would be a very efficient, trivial way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with using GetType() is that it fails if you have 2 'dataless' cases.

Here is one way to do it: (Edited because the previous UnionTagReader was not being cached)

```
type MyDU =
    | Case1
    | Case2
    | Case3 of int
    | Case4 of int

type TagReader<'T>() =
    let tr = 
        assert FSharpType.IsUnion(typeof<'T>)
        FSharpValue.PreComputeUnionTagReader(typeof<'T>, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)

    member this.compareCase (x:'T) (y:'T) =
        (tr x) = (tr y)

let tr = TagReader<MyDU>()

let c1 = Case1
let c2 = Case2
let c3 = Case3(0)
let c3' = Case3(1)
let c4 = Case4(0)

assert (c1.GetType() = c2.GetType() )  //this is why you can not use GetType()

assert tr.compareCase c1 c1
assert not (tr.compareCase c1 c2)
assert tr.compareCase c3 c3'
assert not (tr.compareCase c3 c4)
```

Comment: +1, though since yours is the only correct answer I wish I could upvote more than once.  But something seems odd here with type inference -- I wouldn't think you'd need the two generic declarations, but you do.  And somehow, we end up with `tagReader` as a `'UnionType -> int` even though `PreComputeUnionTagReader` is a non-generic `obj -> int`.  Can you explain any of this, or can you point to some documentation that would?

Comment: phoog: I have no documentation.  I too found out that the static inference was causing my casts from obj -> int to an 'UnionType -> int to fail. So I move the code to where it was not subject to static inference. My vague guess is that when I moved it out it went from a functional static inference rules to .net object variance rules.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can improve your example like so:

```
let compare = function
| MyString _, MyString _, | MyInt _, MyInt _ -> true
| _ -> false
```

But here's the best way (with minimal reflection!):

```
let compare a b = a.GetType () = b.GetType ()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type MyUnion =
    | MyString of string
    | MyInt of int

let x = MyString("hello")
let y = MyString("bye")
let z = MyInt(25)

let compareCases a b =
    FSharpValue.GetUnionFields (a, a.GetType()) |> fst
        = (FSharpValue.GetUnionFields (b, b.GetType()) |> fst)
```

though, in order to do anything with the values, you will still need to pattern match, so I do not quite see the point, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

```
let compareCases (a : MyUnion) (b : MyUnion) =
    a.GetType().Name = b.GetType().Name
```